# jQuery: using Append() with anchor links in WebKit(Chrome/Safari)

Tags: jquery, image, webkit, append

Been trying to add an image before the closing of the anchor tag:

```
<body>
    <a href="http://www.test.com/">http://www.test.com/</a>
</body>
```

If I use:

```
$("a").append("<img src='testimage.png' /");
```

No image will appear in WebKit (Chrome, Safari, etc). Firefox and IE works fine. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: If correcting the XML doesn't help, it is possible the image is appended but isn't displayed - possibly due to css, or other scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with proper xml:

```
$("a").append("<img src='testimage.png' />");
#                                        ^-- there
```

Comment: thanks for the spot. I should know now that WebKit doesn't auto correct a lot of the small mistakes like IE and FF does

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested if this solves your issue, but including a closing gt for your img might help:

```
$("a").append("<img src='testimage.png' />");
```